# Finding joint probability distribution of standard normal with constraints

Tags: probability, self-study, joint-distribution

> Let $X, Y \mathop{\sim}\limits^{iid} N(0,1)$.
>
> a) Suppose $X < Y$, find the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$.
>
> b) What is the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ if $X = Y$?

We know that $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ and $f_Y(y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}.$

When there is no constraint, the joint pdf is $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)\times f_Y(y),$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Now,

For part a), my idea is that $f(x,y|x<y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{P(x < y)}$ where $P(x<y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y\!f(x,y)dxdy.$ However, this integration does not seem to have a close form. Probably, Am I using a wrong idea here?

For part b), I needed some idea on how to proceed with solving it.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. Please use the tag [tag:self-study]. Also, it seems you have sought a response from ChatGPT and (partly) used 
  it to frame your post. Please note that ChatGPT and similar Large 
  Language Models are often highly unreliable in formulating 
  coherent statistical assertions. Apropos to that, it is a common 
  precedent here to abstain from using such to create a post, and 
  to tread with caution here.

Comment: "$X=Y$" is difficult to reconcile with $X,Y$ i.i.d. Apart from the issue of whether there is a joint conditional density at all, you might get different conditional distributions conditioning on $X-Y\approx 0$ or conditioning on $\frac{X}{Y}-1\approx 0$ as an example of the Borel–Kolmogorov paradox.  It might be worth simulating the two cases and looking at the empirical conditional variances and the empirical conditional densities of $X$ in the two cases.

Comment: "$X<Y$" is easier to handle.  Clearly the joint conditional density will be zero for $x>y$.  You might then then use symmetry/exchangeability to argue that the rest of the  joint conditional density must be double the original joint unconditional density.

Comment: @Henry, thank you for your help. I was able to show that part a) is $2f(x,y)$ as you pointed out. But, I am yet to figure out the part b).

Comment: That's not the correct answer to (a), though, because $2f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ integrates to $2$ rather than $1$ as it should.  You might find it helpful to sketch the region where $X\lt Y.$

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your observation, I will take a look at it again and work with your suggestion.